# npm publish from github actions - Cannot publish over existing version

Tags: npm, github-actions

I have a github action that cd's into a bunch of different package folders and tries to publish each one. I'd like to be able to run `npm publish` and have it only publish packages with a version update. The only trouble is that the github action isn't aware of the app's state or which packages I'm trying to publish.

Ideally, I'd want `npm publish` to just fail on the packages it can't publish and continue on. But since it exits with an error, it kills the action. Any ideas?

Comment: It does. I can't believe it was that easy.